# On injectivity of the Banach space $C_0(X)$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, such that $C_0(X)$ is an injective Banach space, *i.e.* a $\mathfrak{P}_\lambda$ space for some $\lambda\geq 1$.

- Is it true that $X$ is compact?
- If additionally $X$ is a locally compact group, is it true that $X$ is finite?

Comment: NO. $C_0(X\setminus\{x_0\})$ is complemented in $C(X)$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I agree for the 1st question, but is the 2nd one also obvious?

Comment: Regarding your second question, one obvious attempt seems to be ruled out by http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Extremally-disconnected_space which says, essentially, that the only compact groups $G$ for which $C(G)$ is $1$-injective are the finite ones.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: It's not obvious, but probably not too difficult (modulo a structure theorem of LCA groups) to show it's YES. Every LCA group $G$ has a compact open subgroup $K$ such that $G/K$ is a Lie group. One can probably show $K$ is finite and then $G=K$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thanks (by the way, you meant locally compact, not LCA, right?)

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Oh. Somehow I assumed $G$ was abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C_0(G)$ is not injective for infinite $G$, because it is not complemented in $L_\infty(G)$.

See [Lau, Anthony To Ming; Losert, Viktor. Complementation of certain subspaces of $L_\infty(G)$ of a locally compact group. Pacific Journal of Mathematics 141 (1990), no. 2, 295--310](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102646608), corollary 3.